# JSON - Get average from values in php

Tags: php, json

I made a search but no success. I always get some error...
What I want is, get the average of the values "Import" grouped by date.

I appreciate if someone can help me...

My JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "Date": "2019-03",
    "Import": "200",
    "Export": "50"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-03",
    "Import": "800",
    "Export": "200"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-04",
    "Import": "100",
    "Export": "600"
  }
]
```

My PHP Script:

```
$url = dirname(__DIR__  ) . '/admin/json/all.json';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$array_origin = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$stack=array(); 
foreach ($array_origin as $v) {
    $stack[$v['Date']]['Import'] = isset($v['Date']) ? $stack[$v['Date']]['Import'] + $v['Import'] : $v['Import'];
    $stack[$v['Date']]['Export'] = isset($v['Date']) ? $stack[$v['Date']]['Export'] + $v['Export'] : $v['Export'];
    $stack[$v['Date']]['Average_Import'] = 'GET HERE AVERAGE';

}

echo '<pre>' . var_export($stack, true) . '</pre>';
```

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Comment: what is $stack ?

Comment: Sorry, i forget add to code :) 
$stack=array();

Comment: `I always get some error.` - which is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is, get the average of the values "Import"

Simple

```
$array_origin = json_decode('[
  {
    "Date": "2019-03",
    "Import": "200",
    "Export": "50"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-03",
    "Import": "800",
    "Export": "200"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-04",
    "Import": "100",
    "Export": "600"
  }
]', true);


echo round(array_sum(array_column($array_origin, 'Import'))/count($array_origin));
```

Output

```
367
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b8525b13d994e94e345d7acbb58b7ff05ff029d7)

This is an aggregate value of all the rows, so it doesn't make much sense to store it in each of the rows.

If not all rows have the `Import` you can just make the column a variable and count that instead:

```
$import = array_column($array_origin, 'Import'); //["200","800","100"]
echo round(array_sum($import)/count($import));
```

**UPDATE**
While this wasn't clear

> No, because as you see, have a filter "by date". You are printing all itens, not by date. :( –

It's still a trivial problem (once you know how many items there are and the total).

```
$stack = [];

foreach ($array_origin as $v) {
    $key = $v['Date'];

    if(!isset($stack[$key])) $stack[$key] = [];

    $stack[$key]['Import'] = isset($stack[$key]['Import']) ? $stack[$key]['Import'] + $v['Import'] : $v['Import'];
    $stack[$key]['Export'] = isset($stack[$key]['Export']) ? $stack[$key]['Export'] + $v['Export'] : $v['Export'];
    //track the number of items
    $stack[$key]['items'] = isset($stack[$key]['items'] ) ? ++$stack[$key]['items'] : 1;
    $stack[$key]['Average_Import'] = 'GET HERE AVERAGE';
}

//cant average tell you know what they are, this will have to be done after the foreach
array_walk($stack,function(&$item){
   $item['Average_Import'] = $item['Export']/$item['items'];
   return $item;
});

print_r ($stack);
```

Output

```
Array
(
[2019-03] => Array
    (
        [Import] => 1000
        [Export] => 250
        [items] => 2
        [Average_Import] => 125
    )

[2019-04] => Array
    (
        [Import] => 100
        [Export] => 600
        [items] => 1
        [Average_Import] => 600
    )
 )
```

Additionally, this `foreach` loop was just littered with issues, so I fixed them up.  Mostly little things...

For example:

```
 isset($v['Date']) ? $stack[$v['Date']]['Import'] + $v['Import']
```

This does nothing to prevent read errors from addition, for this value `['Import']`.  This `isset($v['Date'])` can be true all day long and that tells us nothing about if `$stack[$v['Date']]['Import']` is set or not.  If it's not set and we try to read it for addition (have to know its value to add to it) we will get a notice for undefined index.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f46039f79b9ad0fcf099b61ebf5000bc028fae3d)

Now **If you don't want to track those item counts** ( for whatever reason )

This is a nice trick (plus its fun) to get the number of items for a given date:

```
  $num_dates = array_count_values(array_column($array_origin, 'Date'));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [2019-03] => 2
    [2019-04] => 1
)
```

That will give you that information, Then use `$num_dates` in the callback (literally, pun intended) and the `key` of the item:

```
foreach ($array_origin as $v) {
    $key = $v['Date'];

    if(!isset($stack[$key])) $stack[$key] = [];

    $stack[$key]['Import'] = isset($stack[$key]['Import']) ? $stack[$key]['Import'] + $v['Import'] : $v['Import'];
    $stack[$key]['Export'] = isset($stack[$key]['Export']) ? $stack[$key]['Export'] + $v['Export'] : $v['Export'];
    $stack[$key]['Average_Import'] = 'GET HERE AVERAGE';
}

$num_dates = array_count_values(array_column($array_origin, 'Date'));
array_walk($stack,function(&$item,$key)use($num_dates){
    //may want to check if $key exists (but it should always)
   $item['Average_Import'] = $item['Export']/$num_dates[$key];
   return $item;
});
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [2019-03] => Array
        (
            [Import] => 1000
            [Export] => 250
            [Average_Import] => 125
        )

    [2019-04] => Array
        (
            [Import] => 100
            [Export] => 600
            [Average_Import] => 600
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/831c046a97ad5970437df6526a64bb7a3db80ab0)

Comment: Does it not work? `200 + 800 + 100 = 1100 / 3 = 366.66666`

Comment: No, because as you see, have a filter "by date". You are printing all itens, not by date. :(

Comment: No I don't see, as that is never mentioned in the question.  Maybe you have this `$stack[$v['Date']]['Import']` what does that mean to me?  This is what you asked for `What I want is, get the average of the values "Import"` not `What I want is, get the average of the values "Import" [grouped by date]`  Words matter.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just updated the topic. Sorry.

Comment: Fixed with your script. 
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Sure, it was fun...  I love array manipulation (for some odd reason)

Answer (score 0):

```php
$array_origin = json_decode('[
  {
    "Date": "2019-03",
    "Import": "200",
    "Export": "50"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-03",
    "Import": "800",
    "Export": "200"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2019-04",
    "Import": "100",
    "Export": "600"
  }
]', true);

$counts = [];

$imports = [];


foreach ($array_origin as $data) {
    if (isset($data['Import']) && isset($data['Date'])) {
        if (!isset($counts[$data['Date']])) {
            $counts[$data['Date']] = 0;
            $imports[$data['Date']] = 0;
        }
        $counts[$data['Date']]++;
        $imports[$data['Date']] = intval($data['Import']) + $imports[$data['Date']];
    }
}

$importAverage = [];

foreach ($imports as $date => $importSum) {
    $importAverage[$date] = $importSum > 0 ? $importSum / $counts[$date] : 0;
}

var_dump($importAverage);
```

```
array (size=2)
  '2019-03' => int 500
  '2019-04' => int 100
```